# How to flash a ROM to the Android emulator

Tags: rom, rom-flashing, android-emulator

Any idea about flash a ROM to the Android emulator?

I found this post:

http://android.modaco.com/content/general-discussion/289928/testing-getting-an-emulator-up-and-running-a-full-rom-with-the-market-etc/

But it just with platform 1.5 and update-cm-3.6.5-signed.system.img.zip,but I want to try the
CyanogenMod 6.1.1,I can not found the related system.img.zip.

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be difficult.  I would assume CyanogenMod doesn't necessarily cater to the "hardware" of the emulator.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985384/run-custom-rom-on-android-emulator

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could used yaffs2 image of the system and use that following the steps on the link you posted, but you will probably run in to driver issues with the "hardware"