# Run custom ROM on emulator/VM

Tags: custom-roms, android-emulator, aosp

Before I want to begin, I know this question has been asked, but I only found old answers or not really what I was looking for.

So, I want to build a custom ROM, and I'm sort of a beginner and I'm still reading about this, what I know so far about this is that you have to download and build AOSP, get a build number and a binary related to a real device (Nexuses or Pixels)

Here's where I don't understand, let's say I compiled everything and at the end I have the image, next step is to have the image flashed to a device, I don't have any android device, especially Google proprietary devices, nor I can afford one. Isn't there any possibility to run it on VM or emulators or things like this?

As of writing this, I'm going to build AOSP(ID :SQ1D.220205.004) to learn a bit about the process, but any tips on how to learn more about this is more than welcomed, and also the main question on how to run the image on my PC first.

I'm running on Arch Linux by the way.

Comment: There were a few old questions on here about the same issue, but [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4486/44325) has a comment linking to [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25985384/2821954) with quite detailed steps.

Comment: hmm AVD, might be the answer, I hope so though, now I have to wait until AOSP is compiled